# Groovy script-Issue while accessing 3rd level child from JSON file

Tags: json, groovy, jsonslurper

I need help to access these nodes from given JSON:

( all the values which are true or false)

1. billingAddress
2. shippingAddress
3. duplicate

```
{
    "active": "true",
    "groups": {
        "uid": "zzzz",
        "integrationKey": " "
    },
    "name": "ancd",
    "addresses": [
        {
            "town": "ewqe",
            "shippingAddress": "true",
            "postalcode": "1234",
            
            "region": {
                "isocode": "US-MI",
                "country": {
                    "isocode": "US",
                    "integrationKey": ""
                }
            },
            "district": "",
            
            "streetnumber": "",
            "billingAddress": "false",
            "duplicate": "false",
            "company": "dasdsfsdf",
            
            "fax": "",
            "pobox": "",
            "phone1": "",
            "cellphone": "",
            
        },
        {
            "town": "d",
            "shippingAddress": "true",
            "postalcode": "1234",
            
            "region": {
                "isocode": "US-MI",
                "country": {
                    "isocode": "US",
                    "integrationKey": ""
                }
            },
            "district": "",
            "streetname": "absnadbasnd",
            "streetnumber": "",
            "billingAddress": "false",
            "duplicate": "false",
            "company": "dmnsmnmnfmfn",
            "fax": "",
            "pobox": "",
            "phone1": "",
            "cellphone": "",
            "publicKey": "zxzx_3390_00_00|zxzx|KNA1|WE",
            
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried replce all to replce all "true" with true but that is not working.

I also tried this code but its giving error ,kindly help :
error -"java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch@ line 18 in script2.groovy"

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

import groovy.json.*

def Message processData(Message message) { 
    def body = message.getBody(java.lang.String) as String ;
    def data = new JsonSlurper().parseText(body);
    data.active = convertToBoolean(data.active);

    data.buyer = convertToBoolean(data.buyer);
    data.addresses.shippingAddress = convertToBoolean(data.addresses.shippingAddress);



    // data.replaceAll("false", false);
//  data.replaceAll("true", true); 
    //   data.replaceAll[:"true", :true] ;
//  data.replaceAll[:"false", :false];
    
    message.setBody(new JsonBuilder(data).toPrettyString());
    return message;
}



//Boolean Conversion
static Object convertToBoolean(Object inputValue){
        if(inputValue.equals("true")){
          return true;
        }else{
          return false;
        }
}
```

tried attached code

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to replace the `"true"|"false"` values in original JSON-String.

```
import groovy.json.*

String txt = '{     "active": "true",     "groups": {         "uid": "zzzz",         "integrationKey": " "     },     "name": "ancd",     "addresses": [         {             "town": "ewqe",             "shippingAddress": "true",             "postalcode": "1234",                          "region": {                 "isocode": "US-MI",                 "country": {                     "isocode": "US",                     "integrationKey": ""                 }             },             "district": "",                          "streetnumber": "",             "billingAddress": "false",             "duplicate": "false",             "company": "dasdsfsdf",                          "fax": "",             "pobox": "",             "phone1": "",             "cellphone": "",                      },         {             "town": "d",             "shippingAddress": "true",             "postalcode": "1234",                          "region": {                 "isocode": "US-MI",                 "country": {                     "isocode": "US",                     "integrationKey": ""                 }             },             "district": "",             "streetname": "absnadbasnd",             "streetnumber": "",             "billingAddress": "false",             "duplicate": "false",             "company": "dmnsmnmnfmfn",             "fax": "",             "pobox": "",             "phone1": "",             "cellphone": "",             "publicKey": "zxzx_3390_00_00|zxzx|KNA1|WE",                      }     ] }'

txt = txt.replaceAll( /"(true|false)"/, '$1' )

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText txt

assert Boolean == json.addresses*.shippingAddress*.class.first()
assert true == json.addresses*.shippingAddress.first()
assert false == json.addresses*.billingAddress.first()
```

Having said that, you don't have to parse/build your JSON at all, the replacement will do.